# wp_handle_upload() - how to upload to a custom subdirectory within uploads

Tags: uploads

wp_handle_upload() works for me, but uploads files where it wants (uploads/year/month).

Question: Is there any way to tell it to upload files to a custom dir (uploads/mycustomdir)? Or is there some other function which could do this?

What I tried:

1. php's move_uploaded_file() (wasn't able to figure the target directory parameter - this is for a plugin and I need it to work for everyone regardless of their dir structure).
2. https://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins

I pasted this code into my plugin's core file. Nothing happened. But I see in the comments this seems to work for people.

PLEASE if you have an answer, give a complete one. I'm able to get $_FILES['myfile']. What steps to take from there to make that file go to uploads/mycustomfolder?

Answer (score 9):

You can work on the idea that Joost provided and use the `upload_dir` filter to temporarily set the upload path to somewhere else.

```
/**
 * Override the default upload path.
 * 
 * @param   array   $dir
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_141088_upload_dir( $dir ) {
    return array(
        'path'   => $dir['basedir'] . '/mycustomdir',
        'url'    => $dir['baseurl'] . '/mycustomdir',
        'subdir' => '/mycustomdir',
    ) + $dir;
}
```

And then in practice, it's as easy as:

```
// Register our path override.
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );

// Do our thing. WordPress will move the file to 'uploads/mycustomdir'.
$result = wp_handle_upload( $_FILE['myfile'] );

// Set everything back to normal.
remove_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_141088_upload_dir' );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for guidance. This almost works, but now I'm getting: "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/mycustomdir. Is its parent directory writable by the server?". To me, seems obvious that parent directory is writable by the server, as uploads there work just fine.

Comment: Trying to solve above problem, I tried creating mycustomdir on plugin activation, using this snippet: http://www.wpmayor.com/code-snippet-to-create-a-directory-within-uploads-folder/  Result: on my localhost it works (and so does your code) - but on production server it says: "The plugin generated 233 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."